# Python Abstract Method With It's own __init__ function

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, abc

How can I define a `__init__` function in both the base and derived abstract classes and have all `self.*` be available in the abstract method? For example:

What is the proper way of utilizing functions that are imported in the base class of an abstract class? For example: in base.py I have the following:

```
import abc

class BasePizza(object):
    __metaclass__  = abc.ABCMeta
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstname = "My Name"

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_ingredients(self):
         """Returns the ingredient list."""
```

Then I define the method in diet.py:

```
import base

class DietPizza(base.BasePizza):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lastname = "Last Name"

    @staticmethod
    def get_ingredients():
        if functions.istrue():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

However when I run `diet.py` I only have access to `self.lastname`. I would want `DietPizza` to have both `self.firstname` and `self.lastname`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `BasePizza.__init__` is a concrete method; just invoke it using `super()`:

```
class DietPizza(BasePizza):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lastname = "Last Name"
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. I'll accept it in 10 minutes when they let me.

Comment: Do you not need to specify the calling object and class, i.e. `super(DietPizza, self).__init__()`?

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain: Not in Python 3, no.

Comment: @MartijnPieters touché, thanks.